# Using the same formula for each row in sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I want for every row in my sheet to calculate a score using a formula. So the same formula for each row. I tried this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(min((((C3:C100)/4)+((K3:K100)*4/10)+(M3:M100)+((N3:N100)/2.5)+((O3:O100)/5)+(R3:R100)+(T3:T100)+((P3:P100)/3)+(V3:V100))/23))
```

But it does calculate at all, for any row. (I am starting from row 3)

Why does it act like this? Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `min()` supposed to be doing? It currently does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It's always best to provide us a link to your sheet, so we can see what you're trying to accomplish (or at least create a copy without sensitive data and share that).

If you want the same exact formula for each row, you will get the same exact result with your current formula. Also, do you mean to SUM the range values you have provided inside the formula? If so, you need to alter your formula to look like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(min((((sum(C3:C100)/4)+(sum(K3:K100)*4/10)+sum(M3:M100)+(sum(N3:N100)/2.5)+(sum(O3:O100)/5)+sum(R3:R100)+sum(T3:T100)+(sum(P3:P100)/3)+SUM(V3:V100))/23)))
```

Please be more specific about exactly what you want the formula to calculate on each row. If it's on row 20, for example, do you still want rows 3-100 to be considered? Or just rows 20-100? WHAT data do you need to be considered on each row's formula, in other words?

Here's a sheet I created to try to understand what you want:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GRdU6NLMWx2xPXDNp21VzYRQRj6cjNbL4RGVUV2x8Wk/edit?usp=sharing